# Angularjs directive not work to added by javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, directive

I want to normally work my directive  When I add this element by click event.

I checked that the originally declared code works as expected.

This html element is added by javascript function when be called some click event

```
<input type="text" reg="'^[-+]?([0-9]|[0-8][0-9]|9[0])$'" reg-check>
```

Here is my directive code

```
TEST.directive('regCheck', function(){
    return {
        restrict : 'A',
        scope: {
            reg : '='
        },
        link : function(scope, element, attrs){
            var regEx = new RegExp(scope.reg);
            var previousValue;
            console.log(regEx);
            $(element).on('keyup' ,function(){
                var dInput = element[0].value
                console.log(dInput);
                if(regEx.test(dInput) || dInput =='' || dInput =='-') previousValue = dInput
                else element[0].value = previousValue
            });
        }
    }
})
```

I think that this problem works cause by jquery event not rendered to added element. 
So I try to

```
$(document).on('keyup', element ,function(){
     var dInput = element[0].value
     console.log(dInput);
     if(regEx.test(dInput) || dInput =='' || dInput =='-') previousValue = dInput
     else element[0].value = previousValue
});
```

It's not work too. What should I do?

Comment: that element code shown by ng-bind-html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are unable to have your directive fire on the `keyup` event?

`$` is not defined.  Simple mod gets you going:

```
app.directive('regCheck', function(){
  return {
    restrict : 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',
    scope: {
        reg : '='
    },
    link : function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel){
        var regEx = new RegExp(scope.reg);
        var previousValue;
        console.log(regEx);
        element.on('keyup' ,(ngModel) => {
            console.log('value', ngModel.target.value);
            var dInput = element[0].value
            console.log(dInput);
            if(regEx.test(dInput) || dInput =='' || dInput =='-') previousValue = dInput
            else element[0].value = previousValue
        });
    }
  }
})
```

And add a ng-model to your input and the value of the input is output to the console on every keyUp event.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="inputValue" reg-check reg="'^[-+]?([0-9]|[0-8][0-9]|9[0])$'">
```

Note: I did not check the logic of the directive or regEx as I dont think that was the question.

Comment: I solved problem. the problem is that after added elements by javascript are not checked by $complie So angular can't check that element. 
Thank you for your helping. 

I referenced [this](https://github.com/incuna/angular-bind-html-compile/blob/master/angular-bind-html-compile.js)